Ubuntu nginx FTP - can't create new file
I have 2 servers which are equaly configured. One is 1 year old and has older Ubuntu version while the other one has the latest.
When I log into the latest one over FTP and try to create a file, it fails and gives the response 550 Permission denied
I've seen this question and answer and 100 similar ones where the answers are always "set the correct folder permission to 777 or 755 and the correct ownership".
But the folder html which I try to create a file in is 777 and the ownership the same as the user I'm logged over FTP to, same goes for the parent folder www.
Is this a bug with the latest version?
What files should I show you?
I'm already struggling for many hours with this.
EDIT:
namei -l /var/www/ gives:
f: /var/www/
drwxr-xr-x root   root   /
drwxr-xr-x root   root   var
drwxrwxrwx beavis beavis www

nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}

And the FTP software vsftpd.conf:
listen=NO

listen_ipv6=YES

anonymous_enable=NO

local_enable=YES

write_enable=YES

dirmessage_enable=YES

use_localtime=YES

xferlog_enable=YES

connect_from_port_20=YES

secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

pam_service_name=vsftpd

rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO

pasv_min_port=10000
pasv_max_port=10100

EDIT based on the answer here:
"First off, it's 2024 not 1994" I'm usually using SSH but I do need FTP sometimes, so please stay objective. I would waive it when everything else would work properly, but it doesn't. When I try to overwrite a file using PHP which was also created with PHP with the permission 644, then it doesn't work. So it's not just FTP but something is wrong with the system, period. I configured it the same way I did with the older server though where everything works as it should. So I'm guessing that as soon as the problem with FTP is figured out, everything else would also work as it should. Btw sorry for my bad english :)

Please provide: used FTP server software, actual configuration of said server software, the output of namei -l /path/to/problematic/folder .

Thanks for the response, I edited the question, please check it out @GeraldSchneider

What Ubuntu versions are "the older" and "the latest" exactly? Is vsftpd even used (check sudo ss -tnl |grep :21)? What does the log say about the upload attempts (should be /var/log/vsftpd.log)? What's the deal with nginx? nginx is not involved in uploads by an FTP daemon.

In your SO question you claim that you can create a file, but can't overwrite it. Is this the same case here? If yes, please add the output of lsattr $FILE where $FILE is a file you can't overwrite.

The one on the first server is 22.04 and the one on new one is 24.10. I just figured out that the overwriting problem was PHP 8.3 fault, the function "copy" in this version doesn't overwrite files any more, they need to be deleted first, so it's not related to this problem with FTP.

sudo ss -tnl |grep :21 gives: LISTEN 0      32                 *:21               : @GeraldSchneider

Sorry it's 24.04 not .10

Please edit all information in the question and format it properly so it's readable.

the function "copy" in this version doesn't overwrite files any more, they need to be deleted first - that's wrong, it still overwrites just fine.

So the best solution would be to just avoid all the crap that was released after 22.04 and stick with that version?

The best solution would be to provide the requested the information (all of it) so the actual problem can be found and solved. From everything you did and did not provide i have the impression that you are either using a different ftpd than you think or you have an unusual filesystem configuration. But with the current information that's impossible to verify.

(This is mostly comment, but space and formatting limited).

I have 2 servers which are equaly configured

Hmmm.

the answers are always "set the correct folder permission to 777

That's rarely the right solution.

But the folder html which I try to create a file in is 777

Don't do that.

When I log into the latest one over FTP

First off, it's 2024 not 1994. There is NO good reason to still be using FTP. It's a simple protocol but has issues with confidentiality and NAT traversal. Really you should be using scp or sftp.

drwxrwxrwx beavis beavis www

If you are getting a "permission denied" error then the most likely candidates are the FTP server is configured to deny write access, the filesystem is mounted read-only or there is some Mandatory Access Control in play.
Check the config file for your FTP server (you didn't say what you were using so we can't advise where to look for that/what should be in there).
Check the filesystem is mounted rw with the mount command.
For MAC - on Ubuntu, this is probably going to be Apparmor - check if you have a file in /etc/apparmor.d/ matching the name of your FTP server.
Systemd also implements MAC - check the unit file for your FTP server. You can get the location of this from systemctl status $YOURFTPSERVICE.
Once you have resolved the immediate issue, fix your permissions properly.

Please check my latest edit. What does MAC anything to do with ti?

MAC = Mandatory Access Control

I have created another question but on stackoverflow, maybe it will help to figure out the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79177661/php-cannot-overwrite-a-file-that-was-also-created-with-php
